# Missing Messages Java Socket

Tags: java

I have a what it supposed to be a P2P structured overlay, The server starts, listens for a registration message from the client and then is supposed to send a confirmation to the client.

The problem is I'm only getting 1 confirmation even though 10 are sent out. To simplify I'm sending a registration from the client in the StartNode() call and what I want is for the node to start listening for a response once the registration message is sent, but only one of confirmation messages is being received.

My registration if working fine. My server gets all 10 messages and sends out confirmations on the corresponding ports, but only 1 confirmation is recieved. I think the problem might be with how I'm listening for confirmations, though it's the same code I used in the server so I'm thinking it might be some kind of race condition, because it's not always the same confirmation that's recevied.

```
    //SINGLE CLIENT
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException { 
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            Socket newS = new Socket(args[0],Integer.parseInt(args[1]));            
            Thread mNode = new MessagingNode(newS);
            mNode.start();

        }       
    } 

    public void run() {

        try {
            StartNode();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        boolean confirm = false;
        while (!confirm) {
            System.out.println("listening on port :" + portnumber );
            try {
                nsocket = cssocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } 
            Thread receiver = new MessageReceiver(cssocket,nsocket);
            receiver.start();
        }

}

//RECEIVER CLASS
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Recieving");
    synchronized (socket){
    int dataLength;
     try {
         din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
         dataLength = din.readInt();             
         byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
         din.readFully(data, 0, dataLength);
         Message inbound = new Message(data);                
         if (((int)inbound.messageT) == 2) {
             MessageONSR register = new MessageONSR(data);
             System.out.println(register.toString());
             MessagingNode addNode = new MessagingNode(register);
             if (registry.NodeExists(addNode)) {
                 System.out.println("Registration request un-successful. Messaging Node already exists in overlay. The number of messaging nodes currently constituting the overlay is ("+registry.regC+")");
             } else if (!CheckMismatch(register)) {
                 System.out.println("Registration request un-successful. The number of messaging nodes currently constituting the overlay is ("+registry.regC+")");
             } else {
                 registry.RegisterNodes(addNode);
                 System.out.println("Registration request from " + addNode.portnumber + " successful. The number of messaging nodes currently constituting the overlay is ("+registry.regC+")");
             }
         }  if (((int)inbound.messageT) == 3) {
             MessageRRS register = new MessageRRS(data);
             System.out.println(register.status);
             this.interrupt();

         }
         } catch (SocketException se) {
         System.out.println(se.getMessage());
         } catch (IOException ioe) {
         System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     this.interrupt();
}
}

listening on port :510
listened on port :510
14Sent Registration
11Sent Registration
listening on port :512
listening on port :515
listened on port :515
listened on port :512
12Sent Registration
listening on port :513
listened on port :513
listening on port :510
***listened on port :510
Recieving
30***
10Sent Registration
listening on port :511
listened on port :511
19Sent Registration
listening on port :520
listened on port :520
13Sent Registration
listening on port :514
listened on port :514
18Sent Registration
listening on port :519
listened on port :519
17Sent Registration
listening on port :518
listened on port :518
15Sent Registration
listening on port :516
listened on port :516
16Sent Registration
listening on port :517
listened on port :517
```

Comment: I don't see where the receiver loops reading messages, so as far as I can tell, your receiver will die after the first message is read.

Comment: How should I go about doing that?

Comment: Add a loop to the receiver?

Comment: I've tried that, added a sample output if that helps.

Comment: You can see that the sockets are open and listens on all 10 ports, the "30" represents the only successful confirmation recieived.

Comment: why are you passing `cssocket` to the receiver thread?

Comment: why is your `run` synchronized ?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, which makes it hard for people to try it out. Please post a simple, *compilable* code example that shows the problem. There's a bunch of methods missing, which makes it hard to know exactly what's going on.

Comment: I was using the ServerSocket as the lock for the MessageReciever initially, it's not used my the MessageReceiver created by the MNode.

Comment: http://www.fast-files.com/getfile.aspx?file=86419 Here's the entire project (it's multiple classes) the args to the Registry are a port number and the args to the MessagingNOde program are hostname and the former port number.

Comment: I tried removing an adding sychronized in the Receiver because it looks like some kind of issue after the first message is read, but the problem exists either way.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. We don't need more core, we need less code - a simple example that shows the problem. More code = more difficult to debug. You might even find the problem yourself by trying to trim off unnecessary parts of your original code. http://sscce.org/

Answer (score -1):

I figured out my problem, the reason I was only receiving one message is because my ServerSocket was declared as static which means, by the time my listeners started it was overidden to the last Node instantiated.

Comment: Doesn't make sense, unless you have multiple `ServerSockets`, which itself doesn't make sense.